# Query in code returns zero results while returns result in dev console

Tags: apex, trigger

Hi I have following Situation:

I have a trigger defined on parent object, After Insert but I am not getting any results while querying on child.

**Example:**

```
public  List<Child__C> getCHDDetails(List<Parent__C> lstPARENT){


        //adding Parent Ids in a set
        set<Id> setPARENTIds = new set<Id>();
        for(PARENT__c r : lstPARENT){
            setPARENTIds.add(r.Id);
        }

        // Fetching CHILD Records
        List<Child__c> lstCHILDDetails = new List<Child__c>();


       lstCHILDDetails = [select Id, Name  from CHILD__c where Relation_Field__c IN : setPARENTIds]; 

        return lstCHILDDetails ;
    }
}
```

Upon checking debug log, set of parents contains id, while query is resulting into zero records.

But same query is giving results when executing in dev console.

Kindly help here.

Comment: after inserting parent record did you assign parent id to  Relation_Field__c in child__C ?

Comment: Its looking you have inserted parent record no doubt, But you are not creating any relation between parent child

Comment: Yes, NITESH, if we execute the same query in dev Console its returning child records.

Comment: then add system.debug  for setPARENTIds  whether its have any ids ?

Comment: yes ,
verified the debug as well  set containing Ids of parent.

Comment: Then u need to share more code, code you shared have no problem with it .

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance, and a good one, that you still don't have your child records, since you're querying in a an after insert trigger of your parent.
Are you sure that you have you child records created in this step?
Maybe try doing this, whatever you're trying, in an after insert of your child objects.
Everying seems fine with your code. ;)

Regards

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply,
But here  i have a situation that based on some parent field's Old Vale (which we can get form Trigger.OldMap) value i need to check for some conditions,.
If i implement the trigger logic in child object then i won't be able to get the old vale of parent field even i write a query to fetch data from Parent.

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: First you need to clarify and provide more information in your question. 
There is probably something wrong in the way you are trying to approach this, so provide more info, so we can help.

Comment: It makes no sense. If you say you have parent and child at that point in time, then you should be able to query child records based on parent records. So again, it looks like you don't have child records in that point in time when you're trying to query them, is that a possibility? Are you maybe creating them somwhere in the meantime, in some trigger or workflow or something?